# Error while adding two time duration using moment

Tags: typescript, time, ionic4

I am trying to add two time duration as below, I am getting only the first assigned valued and not the summed value of the above. 
Please help where it is wrong?

```
public rasiBalance:'';
public sunRise:'';
// storing the values for the above from some other function
 public getDuration(){
    console.log('Rasi Balance:'+this.rasiBalance); //Output : 0.31
    console.log('Sun Rise:'+this.sunRise); // Output: 6.38
let Lagnam1 = '00:00';
Lagnam1 = moment(this.rasiBalance, 'HH:mm').add(this.sunRise, 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm');
console.log('Lagnam 1:'+Lagnam1);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
var moment = require('moment');

let rasiBalance = 0.31;
let sunRise = 6.38;

function getDuration() {
    console.log('Rasi Balance : ' + rasiBalance);
    console.log('Sun Rise : ' + sunRise);
    console.log ("Time addition output :", addTimes(rasiBalance,sunRise));
}

// To add two times
function addTimes(time1,time2){
    let convertedTime1 = convertToHoursAndMinutes(time1);
    let convertedTime2 = convertToHoursAndMinutes(time2);
    return parseFloat(moment(convertedTime1.hours + ":" + convertedTime1.minutes, "HH:mm").add(convertedTime2.hours,"h").add(convertedTime2.minutes,"m").format("HH:mm").replace(":","."));
}

// To split hours and minutes - We can even try to ignore this function 
// if time and minutes can be split easily and fed into moment method inside the addTimes function
function convertToHoursAndMinutes(valueToConvert){
    var convertedTime = {};
    convertedTime.hours = valueToConvert - parseFloat((valueToConvert % 1).toFixed(2));
    convertedTime.minutes = parseInt((valueToConvert % 1).toFixed(2).substring(2));
    return convertedTime;
}

getDuration();
```

Comment: For Typescript to avoid error message I added ```var convertedTime = {time:0, minutes:0} ````
and you used the property name as 'hours' in function one and property name for the same in function two as 'time'. 
I made both as 'time'.
Now it is working properly.
Thanks